# snakemake batch creation of output

Tags: snakemake

Generating output based on changed input files in Snakemake is easy:

```py
rule all:
    input: [f'out_{i}.txt' for i in range(10)]
rule make_input:
    output: 'in_{i}.txt'
    shell: 'touch {output}'
rule make_output_parallel:
    input: 'in_{i}.txt'
    output: 'out_{i}.txt'
    shell: 'touch {output}'
```

In this case, `make_output` will only run for instances where `in_{i}.txt` have changed.

But suppose the `'out_{i}.txt'` cannot be generated in parallel and I want to generate them in a single step, like,

```py
rule make_output_one_step:
    input: [f'in_{i}.txt' for i in range(10)]
    output: [f'out_{i}.txt' for i in range(10)]
    shell: 'touch {output}'
```

If only one of the `in_{i}.txt` files have changed, I don't need to regenerate all 10 of them.
How can I adjust `make_output_one_step.output` to generate only the needed files?

Comment: Neither `make_output` nor `all` depend on any in_{i}.txt file. There is no "generating output based on changed input files" in your script.

Comment: Oops you're right. Edited to make more clear.

Comment: Your intentions are not clear. First, the script in `make_output` doesn't depend on the input de facto. Next, the `make_input` produces exactly the same files, so the timestamp de facto is not important. And finally I don't see any reason in your intention "to generate them in a single step". I see a logical fallacy.

Comment: You could set a max parallel resource.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, this is meant to be a simple example, not my use case. I do not know what "logical fallacy" you are referring to--could you clarify?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Can you point me to documentation on that? Based on what I can infer from the name, I could see that solving the problem of parallel execution, but it would still end up executing many times when I'd like it to just execute once.

Comment: @goi42 it is very native to assume that each rule depends ONLY on the contents of the files, not the modification times. The rules themselves taken the same input should produce the same output. Touching the file just to change its modification time is a hack. Next, if 10 outputs depend on 10 inputs, you should regenerate all 10 of them: otherwise that is not an actual dependency.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Again, this is just a toy example to illustrate the concept, not what I actually want to do. I do not assume that only contents matter, and that's not what I asked. I just used `touch` in the example for simplicity.
My point is that the 10 outputs do not depend on 10 inputs. Each one of the 10 outputs depends on just one of the 10 inputs. I just want to generate them all in one step, instead of in parallel. Perhaps Snakemake cannot do this, or perhaps it can generate them serially but not in a single step. This is the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some parts of the pipeline to not work in parallel for whatever reason (RAM, internet usage, IO, API limit, etc....) you can make use of [resources](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources).

```
rule all:
    input: [f'out_{i}.txt' for i in range(10)]

rule make_input:
    output: 'in_{i}.txt'
    shell: 'touch {output}'

rule make_output:
    input: 'in_{i}.txt'
    output: 'out_{i}.txt'
    resources: max_parallel=1
    shell: 'touch {output}'
```

And then you can call your pipeline like `snakemake --resources max_parallel=1 --cores 10`. In this case all the jobs of rule `make_input` will run in parallel, but only one instance of `make_output` will run in parallel.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like this is an effective way to prevent rules from running in parallel. It would still require `make_output` being called 10 times instead of in a single step, which is what I would prefer, but perhaps this is the best solution Snakemake can achieve.